# Why does Grover's Diffusion Operator have the word "diffusion" in its name?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Where do I see the diffusion in the Grovers operator?

I would think there should be an analogy to classical diffusion but I am not able to see the correspondence.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to QCSE.  Have you seen [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8574/significance-of-the-term-diffusion-in-grovers-diffusion-operator)?

Comment: No but thanks @Mark. I think this will answer my question.